# how to add class name dynamically in angular9

Tags: html, angular9

I want to add class name as below. Based on a function output, I want to add badge-primary/success/danger.

```
<div class="float-right badge badge-primary"></div>
```

I have tried following way, but it is not working. Please advise a solution.

```
<span class="float-right + viewModel.fetchBadgeColor(staus)"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the class-name is dynamic, the only method I know is:

```
<span [class]="'float-right' + viewModel.fetchBadgeColor(staus)"></span>
```

As the value you assign to the class property is dynamic, you need to wrap the property name in [].